# Exclude maven dependency depending on jdk version

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project that needs to support building with Jdk 8 as well as with Jdk 11. When it is built with Jdk 8 I see it also packages the jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api jar. (This is causing some errors when deploying on a JEE server running on Jdk 8)

The dependency is meant to provide some packages that were excluded from Jdk since version 9 but that are present in Jdk 8. So how can I exclude it only when building with Jdk 8, otherwise it should still be present?

I'm getting the dependency transitively from a few libraries:

```
[INFO]    \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.5.3:compile (version managed from 3.5.3)
[INFO]       +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.5:compile
[INFO]       |  \- (jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:compile - version managed from 2.3.3; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       \- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:compile (version managed from 2.3.3)
```

I read about using maven-compiler-plugin with a configuration like bellow but I can't get it to work as I want to:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeGroupIds>jakarta.xml.bind</excludeGroupIds>
        <excludeArtifactIds>jakarta.xml.bind-api</excludeArtifactIds>
        <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
        <excludeScope>compile</excludeScope>
        <excludeClassifiers>jdk8</excludeClassifiers>
    </configuration>
....
```

Comment: Build on JDK11+ via `--release 8` and add the deps and it will work with JDK11 and JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

I would exclude it everywhere it comes in.

Then you would declare it again as dependency, but in a profile which is activated based on the JDK version, like

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <jdk>11</jdk>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```